# Zend Framework 2 limit REST API to accept only application/json or application/xml

Tags: php, json, rest, zend-framework2

I would like to limit the access to my rest api only with attribute in the request "Accept:" with value "application/json or xml" and that for every rest call. Where and how i can do that in ZF2 separate module only for Rest calls. my implementation is similar to this guide here: [enter link description here](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-create-restful-application/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect a listener to `onroute` event, check the `Accept` header value and return a [406 Not Acceptable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) response for all headers other then `application/json` or `application/xml`.

In `onBootstrap` connect your listener:

```
$eventManager->attach($serviceManager->get('Application\Listener\RestAcceptListener'));
```

In your listener check the `Accept` header

```
/**
 * Check Accept header
 *
 * @param MvcEvent $event
 * @return Response
 */
public function onRoute(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $routeMatch = $event->getRouteMatch();
    $controller = $routeMatch->getParam('controller');

    // To limit for rest calls only you can do some controller check here
    // You can also do instanceof check this is all up to you...
    if( $controller !== 'somecontroller'){
        return;
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $headers = $request->getHeaders();

    $acceptHeader = $headers->get('Accept');

    // Check whether accept type corresponds to the allowed ones
    $accept = array('application/json', 'application/xml');
    if(!$acceptHeader->match($accept)){
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(406);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE:

To make a module check you can use namespace of the controller. For example to check `Application` module using php explode:

```
$parts = explode('\\', $controller, 2);
if ($parts[0] !== 'Application'){
    // We do not have a controller from Application module
    return;
}
```

Comment: can i limit for some specific module? for example when i'm in Rest module instead application?